# Colorbox for loading a DIV from a separate page

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, loading, colorbox, inline

I am using jQuery Colorbox to a page(**index.html**) to load a DIV content from a separate page(**content.html**) located on the same directory.

It **works** on the latest Firefox, Chrome and IE10 **but it doesn't work on IE8**

Can you please help me figure out what's wrong with the code or why the content of the Colorbox is not loading on IE8 at all?

I tried using **inline** but it only seems to work if the DIV is within the same page and doesn't work with a DIV that's on a separate page.

Thank you!

**index.html**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".link").colorbox({href: function(){ return $(this).attr('href') + " #showbox";}
});
```

`<a href="content.html#showbox" class="link">Show the box</a>`

**content.html**

`<div id="showbox">
   <p>Voila!</p>
   </div>`

Comment: did you ever get anywhere with this problem? i'm also trying to use colorbox to load just a part of another page.